# Memoize current user object before_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 3.2. Let's say I have 10 new Photos to be uploaded, I need to associate my `current_user.id` to each new record. For some reasons, the `photos_controller.rb` is blank because it's a nested with another model `Shop`. Here is my code:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true

  before_create :current_user_id
  before_create :associate_current_user

  def current_user_id
    @current_user_id ||= UserSession.find.user.id
  end

  private

  def associate_current_user
    self.user_id = @current_user_id
  end
end
```

It is clear that if there are 10 new records to be created, I want the model to find the `current_user` once, and then take it from the cache (a memoization technique), but because I am using `before_create`, the `current_user` is queried 10 times instead of getting it from cache.

What can I do to cache the `@current_user_id`?

Thanks.

Comment: **This is a model** and `@current_user_id` is an **instance variable**. Each new instance of `Photo` gets it's own `@current_user_id`. Ten instances, ten variables, ten queries.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple : you should **not** do anything related to the session in your model, it breaks the MVC pattern.

Instead, do this in your controller, so you only have to get `current_user.id` once, and assign it to your records.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of logic belongs in the controller.  Move your `current_user_id` method to your `PhotosController` (or to `ApplicationController` if you plan to use this logic in other controllers too). That way it will assign `@current_user` only once per upload action.

Be sure to make it private too.